# Change volume of audio clip

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

I was wondering how I can adjust the volume of an audio clip.

```
public AudioClip collectCoinSound;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.tag != "Player") return;

    GameManager.highscore += 100;
    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(collectCoinSound, transform.position, 0.5f);
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
```

This is one of my scripts containing a sound and I thought I could control it with the last value of PlayClipAtPoint - but it doesn't change anything and the sound is extremly loud.

Thanks in advance :)

Chrizzly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I do it:

```
audio.volume  = 0.5f;
```

the `audio` represents the current `AudioSource` attached to the object that has your script.

Hope it helps.

Comment: hi and thanks for the reply - I tried using this but I guess I made a mistake because now I hear nothing at all. Up until now I haven't used AudioSource within a script.I added `audio.volum = 0.5f` to start and then `audio.Play();` in the OnTrigger method

Comment: My bad. This won't work because you are destroying your object right after you play your AudioSource which is also destroyed together with the object so it will no longer play. I tried using `PlayClipAtPoint` functioin and it worked just fine. The volume of the clip changed according to the third parameter that I passed. Have you tried to set the volume to less than 0.5f? maybe your clip is just really loud. And please check that no other clip is playing at the same time.

Comment: Yeah I guess that is the problem - I can collect coins or shoot very fast consecutively :/ It's like the mario games were you jump down and collect multiple coins...is there another way to adjust the sound? I culd change the coins but it will be difficult with the shooting part

Comment: Do you really need to indicate the location of the sound? if not, maybe you could try the [PlayOneShot](http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html) function.

Comment: Well I guess the problem is solved but my solution is more like 'quick and dirty'.. `void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
  if (other.tag == "Player") {
   GameManager.highscore += 100;
   audio.PlayOneShot(collectCoinSound, 0.5f);
   StartCoroutine(MyMethod());
  }
 }` and then I destroy almost everything but the script in the enumerator - ` IEnumerator MyMethod() {
  gameObject.renderer.enabled = false;
  gameObject.collider2D.enabled = false;
  yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
  Destroy (gameObject);
 }`

Comment: Glad the `PlayOneShot` function helped :)
You might also want to try like this to avoid the use of a coroutine and waiting for fixed 0.5 seconds:

`OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){ if (other.tag == "Player") { 
 GameManager.highscore += 100;
 audio.PlayOneShot(collectCoinSound, 0.5f);
 //disable rendedrer and collider
 while(audio.isPlaying){
 yield return new waitForFixedUpdate();
 }
 Destroy(gameObject);
 }`

Comment: Ah thanks for the help :) I really don't like to use coroutines so this fits better in my code